# Form Semantic UI React

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, element, semantic-ui-react

```
<Form.Select
        label="Customer Id"
        name="customer.id"                                       
        compact
        options={this.state.customer.map(cu => ({                                
           name: cu.Id,
           key: cu.Id,
           value: cu.Name, 
           text: cu.Name
        }))} 
/>
```

I need to use the value of this select to store in a database by sending the value to function. But it is not sending any value? Anyone can help ?

Comment: It would more helpful for people reading if you format your code properly and you have valid syntax. Also, you need to formulate a clear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const options = [
  { key: "m", text: "Male", value: "male" },
  { key: "f", text: "Female", value: "female" },
  { key: "o", text: "Other", value: "other" }
];

_selectGender = (event,val) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(">>", val.value);
};

  <Form.Select
    fluid
    label="Gender"
    options={options}
    placeholder="Gender"
    onChange={this._selectGender}
  />
```

Try like this. 
You'll get value in this.

Comment: Yes I got the value in console.log. But when I try to set state the value inside salesproductid, it is not inserted. my code is : _selectproduct = (event,val) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(">>", val.value)
        this.setState({
            salesproductid : event.target.val
         });      
    }

Comment: _selectGender = (event,val) => {
  event.preventDefault();
this.setState({salesproductid: val.value})
};  You'll have to take val.value, not event.target.value

Comment: still I am not able to get the value inside salesproductid. How to check the value inside salesproductid in same _selectgender function? The value is coming inside that function but not able to assign to salesproductid.

Comment: this.setState({salesproductid: val.value}, () => {
   console.log('updated state in callback fun', this.state)
})

Comment: I saw the value in the console. I have three dropdowns kept inside a form. At the time of submission of form, the value disappears. But thank you very much for your help. I am stuck with this for 5,6 days but still not able to submit in database.